# Issue with exceeding db queries in drupal

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, hosting, vps

We are having a drupal based website hosted at www.fatcow.com. But recently it started giving error of exceeding some maximum number of 'max_questions' resource  error. As described by http://drupal.org/node/38996#comment-6295156 we increased the number of users. But fatcow has a limitation for that. Now we are considering of moving to a VPS. But how do we find the optimum plan for our site?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like Drupal but it tends to be quite resource hungry as you start adding modules and it takes more efforts to have it scale. I would get at least 1 gig of ram in your vps, set the memory limit to at least 128M, customize the mysql server with query cache and max packet size. I would turn on content caching as well - if you have a lot of content that does not change much, it may be an option. Pressflow might be an option. Another option if you are using Drupal 7 with sqlite instead, it all depends on your user usage scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What about hosting providers. I found that Inmotion Hosting would be a solution. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @user1438823, we are using inmotion hosting for more than 3 years, its a better option not a best one.

Comment: If cost is not an issue, I like AWS. I think it is the most flexible and allows scaling instances as needed, starting and ending instances almost instantly and associated services like S3 backup rocks. However, it depends on taste. If you have the budget you may be able to get a dedicated server with 1and1 (entry level is decent at $59). I also like burst.net (I have used all three but I am in no way associated with either). Shop around